# Error when terminal opens; no available formula

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I open my terminal I see the following message

```
Last login: Thu Dec 18 22:00:53 on ttys000
Error: No available formula for php5
```

I have tried to run brew doctor but the error remains. I am using homebrew dd7511b3

If I run brew remove php5, I get

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php5
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Check Your `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, `.bashrc` files, for `php5` entries.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz, found the issue in .bash_profile, found this export PATH="$(brew --prefix php5)/bin:$PATH" in there

Answer (score 1):

When **Terminal** starts and Your default shell is `bash`, those files are executed at startup:

- `.bash_profile`
- `.profile`
- `.bashrc`

(there are also other files whih can be executed, but those are the most common)

Locate anything related with `php5` in those files and resolve Your issue.